# Android SDK | Webservice or method to get the installed Android versions on SDK

Tags: android, web-services, emulation

I am creating a Framework which will provide a UI to create an Emulator.(I don't want to use the SDK UI. This is a requirement). I need a webservice/method which will list me the Android versions available and also the different fields which are required for creating an Emulator. Is anything available?

Answer (score 0):

For getting the installed android sdk versions on a user's computer, you need to locate the path to Android SDK, which can be accomplished by asking the user to give it, or by searching the directories.

For specifications of an Android Emulator, you can take a look at the default AVD manager. I believe these are the least requirements for creating an emulator in android.